# Broken FrameTicks

Tags: plotting, ticks

I am currently trying to understand Ticks.
Ticks or Frameticks are defined in the following way:

```
{{x1,label1,len1},...}  tick marks with specified scaled length
```

Normally one uses major ticks in the form {1,1,{0.01,0}} and minor ticks in the form {1,,{0.005,0}}. This is also what Charting`ScaledTicks does. I witnessed something strange.
**There is a minimum size for a tick!!!**

Following Example:

```
sizetickstable = Table[{0.3 + i*0.3, 0.3 + i*0.3, {2^i*0.0001, 0}}, {i, 1, 12}]
ListPlot[{}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}, FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {testsizeticks, None}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

I am changing the tickssize exponenitally. The result (see below) is, that the first 6 ticks have the same size! This is tragic, because under some circumstances it can lead to major an minor ticks having the same size. Since this all is also dependent on the AspectRatio, this means that in some cases this ticklimit is larger than the whole plot...
[image]
Interestingly, this is only the case for ticks facing inside. Outside facing ticks do not have that problem:

```
sizetickstable = Table[{0.3 + i*0.3, 0.3 + i*0.3, {2^i*0.0001,2^i*0.0001}}, {i, 1, 12}]
ListPlot[{}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}, FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {testsizeticks, None}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: This is wildly speculative:  At some point, your ticks will become smaller than the smallest feature representable on your output device. At that point, I suppose the system must decide whether to draw anything at all (and whatever is drawn will be at that minimum size), or to simply leave the tick off. I think the decision might be to try and draw something anyway. More to the point, what is the context in which this has become a problem for you?

Comment: I think they set a minimum value because ticks aren't visible for very small length. Also, you can always explain tick lengths are in the power of 10 if necessary and draw them. I personally don't feel anything wrong with their design. It's just they set conditions. If you want lines use gridlines.

Comment: I think *"trying to understand Ticks"* is a valid enquiry, with a clearly defined undesirable outcome *"it can lead to major an minor ticks having the same size"* and and inconsistency (AFAIK undocumented) *"this is only the case for ticks facing inside"*.  However, **speculative questions, answers and comments** about *"why"* are not answerable and therefore are **off-topic** here.  I think that question and answers should focus on the *"how"* this is working and *"how"* to obtain the required behaviour.